# Laravel update makes new table rule instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a company table and an attributes table with all sorts of value in it.

One company hasMany attributes and an attribute belongsTo a company.

Now I have a value inside the attributes table with a 'account_nr_start' (for example, when a new user is added to a company its account_id starts counting up from 1000).

Controller:

```
public function __construct(Company $company, User $user)
{
    if(Auth::user()->usertype_id == 7)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $this->company  = $company->Where(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('id', '=', $this->company_id )
                ->orWhere('parent_id','=', $this->company_id);
        }) ;
    }

    $this->user = $user;

    $this->middleware('auth');
}



public function edit(Company $company, CompaniesController $companies)
{
    $companies = $companies->getCompaniesName(Auth::user()->company_id);

    $attributes = $company->attributes('company')
        ->where('attribute', '=', 'account_nr_start')
        ->get();

    foreach ($attributes as $k => $v) {
        $nr_start[] = $v->value;
    }

    return view('company.edit', ['company' => $company, 'id' => 'edit', 'companies' => $companies, 'nr_start' => $nr_start]);
}



public function update(UpdateCompanyRequest $request, $company, Attribute $attributes)
{
        $company->fill($request->input())->save();

        $attributes->fill($request->only('company_id', 'attribute_nr', 'value'))->save();

        return redirect('company');
}
```

HTML/Blade:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('_nr_') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! HTML::decode (Form::label('account_nr_start', trans('common.account_nr_start').'<span class="asterisk"> *</span>', ['class' => 'form-label col-sm-3 control-label text-capitalize'])) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::text('value', $nr_start[0], ["class"=>"form-control text-uppercase"]) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('account_nr_start', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I update a company now, it will upload like the last input here: : [image]

So it makes a new rule, while it needs to edit the current attribute rule instead of making a new rule with an empty company_id/attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think this will fix your problem. The issue you have is the Attribute model is a new instance of the model rather than retrieving the model you need.

before running fill() from the attributes method try this

```
$new_attribute = $attributes->where('company_id', '=', $company->id)->where('attribute', '=', 'account_nr_start')->first();
```

Then run the fill()

```
$new_attribute->fill($request->only('company_id', 'attribute_nr', 'value'))->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, how does the first() method works exactly?

Comment: The first method returns the first out of the database so you only receive the one object you need. If there are going to be multiple in the database you need to access, use the get() method and foreach the objects